# Asp.net MVC does not display the template editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, mvc-editor-templates, editorformodel

**I have the classes:**

```
public class PersonDetailsModel
{
    public string FistName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RegisterCoupleModel
{
    public PersonDetailsModel Groom
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PersonDetailsModel Bride
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string UrlKeyword
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ReCaptcha
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**folder Shared > EditorTemplates**

**PersonDetailsModel.cshtml**

```
@model BindSolution.AndMarried.ViewModel.PersonDetailsModel

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FistName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">     
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FistName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FistName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">     
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">     
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
</div>
```

In my View:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Only the `UrlKeyword` and `ReCapcha` fields are displayed!

Why Asp.net MVC not use templantes in shared folder to display my nested type `PersonDetailsModel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, you could have just edited your other question. :)

Anyway, i don't think that will work. You either need to control the entire template yourself, or let MVC do it all itself. (i could be wrong)

Create an editor template for `RegisterCoupleModel`:

```
@model BindSolution.AndMarried.ViewModel.RegisterCoupleModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Groom)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bride)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UrlKeyword)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReCapcha)
```

Or you could use a `[UIHint("PersonDetailsModel"]` attribute on your `Groom` and `Bride` properties in your ViewModel.

Read up on the remarks section in **[EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406517%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)** for how this all works.

Comment: I thought the context was different:)

Am I required to create the template `RegisterCoupleModel`?
It could not just create the template `PersonDetailsModel`?
I tried to create the template and put the attribute `UIHint("PersonDetailsModel")` but did not work.

Comment: @Riderman - yes, create the template `RegisterCoupleModel`, in addition to the `PersonDetailsModel` one, and it should work. (no need for the UIHint in this case). `Html.EditorForModel` in your main view will render the `RegisterCoupleModel` template, which will then call `PersonDetailsModel` template for `Bride` and `Groom`.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was not necessary creating the `template` RegisterCoupleModel. Thanks again!